# How to disable pretxncommit hooks with mercurial queues or histedit?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook, mercurial-queue

I have some pretxncommit hooks in my local mercurial repository, those hooks are used to check that the commit message includes a reference to a ticket and some other sanity checks.

My problem is that when I try to use mercurial queues, commands like `qnew` try to run these hooks and the one of the ticket checking fails, I have seen the same problem with `histedit` and similar extensions.

Why are pretxncommit hooks executed with these commands? Do they run some kind of internal commit?

How can I make these hooks to be run only on commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a qnew creates a **real commit** and thus invokes all the relevant commit hooks. You can confirm this for yourself by temporarily disabling MQ while you have an MQ patch applied and looking at the log.

There is no way to make the pretxncommit hook apply to only some commands except by jury-rigging something with other hooks:

```
$ cat .hg/hgrc
[hooks]
pre-qnew = touch .hg/skiphook
post-qnew = rm .hg/skiphook
pretxncommit = test -e .hg/skiphook || echo not skipping
$ hg rm README  # make some change
$ hg qnew asdf  # no hook
$ hg qpop
$ hg rm README
$ hg ci -m asdf
not skipping
```

Here our pretxncommit hook makes sure a specific file doesn't exist before running its (trivial) hook, and the pre-/post-qnew hooks create the file and clean it up.

Comment: I don't think this solution makes sense, its kind of a hack. On the other hand, you would think you could solve this with:

pre-commit = do-your-hook
pre-qfinish = do-your-hook

but pre-qfinish doesn't seem to block qfinish :-\

Answer (score 1):

The function `abort_commit_to_wrong_branch` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19349636/350713
shows an approach to run a hook only on a "real" commit, not an MQ commit.
The idea is to check for the attribute `_committingpatch` in `repo`.

If `repo` has '_committingpatch' attribute, then it is an MQ commit in progress.
The relevant line is

```
if hasattr(repo, "_committingpatch"):
```

This is mentioned in the function `newcommit` in
http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/file/7032dcff290c/hgext/mq.py#l293

Answer (score 0):

- pretxncommit works with **all** changes (recordable) inside repo
- if you want ignore mq-operation, you could look for the changeset parents and see if that's a descendant 
  of the qparent/qbase tag or see at WC. Smth. like (dirty from head, not from test) hg id -tr .

Or (maybe delirium) - when you work with MQ, you work with qtip always, sn't it?

```
>hg parents
...
tag:         qtip
tag:         tip
..
```

Comment: Do you mean to check in the hooks theirselves if they are being run as a mq-operation and, if they are, abort them?

Comment: Yes, but not abort, but exit with good errorlevel. BTW, discovered later than answered -qfinish even in this case will be big headache