# precommit mercurial hook to stop commits to the wrong branch

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-hook

I have a piece of software in a Mercurial repository.

I'm packaging my software project as a Debian package. 
It seems the standard way to do this is to have a
separate branch for the Debian package files, 
which live in the `debian` sub-directory.

One problem I keep having is that I forget which branch I am
on and accidentally commit to the wrong branch. This happens
frequently, and is really annoying. When this happens I usually
push to remote before realising the problem, and then have
to fix up the local and remote repositories manually, which is
a pain.

The only option I can think of is to have a pre-commit hook
that aborts if I am trying to make commits to the wrong branch.

To be concrete, let's say the main branch is called `default` and the branch
containing Debian files is called `debian`. Then I want commits to the `default`
branch to succeed only if none of the files in the commit are from the `debian`
directory. I want commits to the `debian` directory to succeed only if all the
files in the commit are in the `debian` directory.

I spent some time reading the chapter on Mercurial Hooks and going through the examples
in the Hg Book, but still have no idea how to go about this. I did get the strong impression
that for something like this I should be calling out to an external Python script, probably
in `.hg/`.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you're spot on that a `precommit` hook can do this.  If you wanted to do it in bash you could go with something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
revs=$(hg log -r "$HG_NODE:tip" --template '{rev} ') #Intentional space after {rev}
rc=0
for rev in $revs
do
    files=$(hg log -r $rev --template '{files}')
    #Above will include discards. So you cannot 'hg cat' them all. So you may want
    #  files=$(hg log -r $rev --template '{file_mods} {file_adds}')
    branch=$(hg log -r $rev --template '{branch}')
    for file in $files
    do
        if [ branch == "debian" ] &&  [ "$(echo $file | grep -v "debian")" != "" ] ; then
          echo "ERROR: Non debian file in debian branch."
          exit 1
        fi
        if [ branch != "debian" ] &&  [ "$(echo $file | grep "debian")" != "" ] ; then
          echo "ERROR: debian file in non-debian branch."
          exit 1
        fi
    done
done
exit $rc
```

Those if/grep lines are almost certainly wrong, but you get the picture.

Comment: Thanks Ry4an, that's super helpful. Is there any advantage to going with shell rather than Python or vice versa?

Comment: python runs in process so it'll be more efficient, but you'll be learning a new not-an-api to get the current branch name and list of files in the commit, whereas you probably already know how to do that in bash.  In the end it's probably more about what you and your team will find easier to customize later on.  Some examples can be found here: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HookExamples

Comment: Hi Ry4an. Not sure what you mean by not-an-api. Do you mean Mercurial doesn't have a fixed "official" API?

Comment: The official API _is_ the command line.  Matt Mackall takes command line backward compatibility incredibly seriously, but the internals, say the function names on the 'repo' object are subject to change at any time.  In practice they don't change all that much, but it's always possible a future Mercurial upgrade would break your python hook, whereas it's guaranteed it won't break your bash hook.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Ry4an's solution as a starting point, I came up with the following script using the new [hglib](http://www.selenic.com/repo/python-hglib) API.

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                         

# Abort commit to the debian branch if it is not contained in a debian                                                                                                    
# subdirectory                                                                                                                                                            

# Similary abort commit to non-debian branches if it is contained in a                                                                                                    
# debian subdirectory                                                                                                                                                     

import hglib, os, sys
client = hglib.open("/home/faheem/hooktest")
ctx = client['tip']
files = ctx.files()  
branch = ctx.branch()

for f in files:
    d = os.path.dirname(f)
    if branch == "debian" and d != "debian":
        sys.exit("cannot commit %s (file not in 'debian' directory) to 'debian' branch"%f)
    if branch != "debian" and d == "debian":
        sys.exit("cannot commit %s (file in 'debian' directory) to non 'debian' branch"%f)
```

Answer (score 0):

A method using in-process hooks is the following code. These
functions can be used in a Mercurial repository's `.hgrc` like this.

```
pretxncommit.foo = python:mercurial_hooks.abort_commit_to_wrong_branch
pre-qfinish.bar = python:mercurial_hooks.qfinish_abort_commit_to_wrong_branch
```

`abort_commit_to_wrong_branch` disallows normal commits to the wrong
branch, but allows MQ commits. `qfinish_abort_commit_to_wrong_branch`
stops qfinish from converting MQ commits on the wrong branch into
regular commits.

I used the function `finish` at
https://bitbucket.org/mirror/mercurial/src/tip/hgext/mq.py?at=default#cl-3034
for reference.

```
def abort_commit_to_wrong_branch(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    """
    Don't allow commits to 'debian' branch including files not
    contained in the 'debian/' directory. Also don't allow commits to
    non-'debian' branches including files contained in the 'debian/'
    directory. Don't restrict MQ commits.
    """
    # If repo has '_committingpatch' attribute, then it is an mq
    # commit in progress, so return 'False'
    import os
    ctx = repo[kwargs['node']]
    files = ctx.files()
    branch = ctx.branch()
    if hasattr(repo, "_committingpatch"):
        for f in files:
            d = os.path.dirname(f)
            if branch == "debian" and d != "debian":
                ui.warn("Warning: committing %s (file not in 'debian' directory) to 'debian' branch. Allowed since this ia an MQ commit.\n"%f)
            if branch != "debian" and d == "debian":
                ui.warn("Warning: committing %s (file in 'debian' directory) to non 'debian' branch. Allowed since this ia an MQ commit.\n"%f)
        return False
    for f in files:
        d = os.path.dirname(f)
        if branch == "debian" and d != "debian":
            ui.warn("Error: cannot commit %s (file not in 'debian' directory) to 'debian' branch\n"%f)
            return True
        if branch != "debian" and d == "debian":
            ui.warn("Error: cannot commit %s (file in 'debian' directory) to non 'debian' branch\n"%f)
            return True

def qfinish_abort_commit_to_wrong_branch(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    """
    Don't allow qfinish on 'debian' branch including files not
    contained in the 'debian/' directory. Also don't allow qfinish on
    non-'debian' branches including files contained in the 'debian/'
    directory. Don't restrict MQ commits.
    """
    from mercurial import scmutil
    import os
    if not repo.mq.applied:
        ui.status(('no patches applied\n'))
        return True
    opts = kwargs['opts']
    # case corresponding to `-a`. no revisions specified.
    if opts.get('applied'):
        revrange = ('qbase::qtip',)
    # case where revision(s) specified
    revrange = kwargs['pats']
    revs = scmutil.revrange(repo, revrange)
    # loop over revisions
    for rev in revs:
        ctx = repo[rev]
        files = ctx.files()
        branch = ctx.branch()
        for f in files:
            d = os.path.dirname(f)
            if branch == "debian" and d != "debian":
                ui.warn("Error: cannot commit %s (file not in 'debian' directory) to 'debian' branch\n"%f)
                return True
            if branch != "debian" and d == "debian":
                ui.warn("Error: cannot commit %s (file in 'debian' directory) to non 'debian' branch\n"%f)
                return True
```